# How to expose method to its sibling and parent only but not to client using that crate in rust

Tags: rust

I have a library with the following structure

```
Cargo.toml
src
    parent_file.rs
    child_folder
        mod.r
        child_file.rs
```

`child_folder/mod.rs`

```
self::child_file::MyStruct;

mod child_file;
```

Is there anyway to block off access of `method` in `child_file` to client that is using this library but still allow `parent_file` to access it?